# Use a value from SELECT in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm selecting a name and a number of sports that name is related to, and I need to only select them when that number of sports is greater than 1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name AS FullName,  
      (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coaches WHERE coaches.name=FullName) AS NrOfSports  
FROM coaches WHERE NrOfSports>1
```

If `WHERE` is removed the query works just fine and displays all rows of which some have only "1" as NrOfSports. When I add it to the `WHERE` clause I get an error because it's not recognized. This baffles me since if I were to use it in another `SELECT` column it would work fine.

Is there a way to do this? It can't be software dependant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Group By` and `Having` instead:

```
SELECT name AS FullName, 
   COUNT(id) AS NrOfSports 
FROM coaches 
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

Your correlated query can work, you just need to move it to a subquery and then you can add the `where` criteria.  However, I believe the `group by` would be faster.

Comment: Your query is a lot better and works. Thank you. I will mark this as correct once I can

Answer (score 2):

### Error explanation

You're getting an error, because `WHERE` clause can not access columns by their alias in the very same level. There are two solutions, which **I don't recommend**, but for the sake of your question I'm attaching:

**(1)** Move your `WHERE NrOfSports > 1` to another level

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        name AS FullName,  
        ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coaches c2 WHERE c1.name = c2.name ) AS NrOfSports  
    FROM coaches c1
    ) foo
WHERE NrOfSports > 1
```

**(2)** Use your condition in the same level.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    name AS FullName,
    ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coaches c2 WHERE c1.name = c2.name ) AS NrOfSports 
FROM 
    coaches c1
WHERE
    ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coaches c2 WHERE c1.name = c2.name ) > 1
```

That would fix the error, **but it still wouldn't be efficient (!)**

### Better approach

Instead, you could combine a power of `GROUP BY` with it's own WHERE clause called `HAVING` to limit your output only to those `name`s that have more than 1 `id`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  name AS FullName,
  count(id) AS NrOfSports 
FROM
  coaches 
GROUP BY
  name
HAVING 
  count(id) > 1
```

Comment: I tried doing that but then it still gives the error for "FullName"

Comment: What have you tried exactly? You should access it via `name` if you're working on the same level.

Comment: I tried copying the entire subquery after WHERE and it would give the same error. I haven't tried just supplying "name" because I wasn't sure whether SQL would make the distinction between the subquery's name and the initial query's name columns. EDIT:: with FullName replaced by name, it prints all of the rows including the ones with 1 sport only.

Comment: I've added explanation in my answer. Notice usage of aliases for table names.

Comment: Remember that especially the second method marked as __(2)__ is an anti-pattern. Never do it like that :-) It would get similar performance results to __(1)__ only if column `NrOfSports` was not being recalculated in the `SELECT` clause

Answer (score 2):

The answer of sgeddes is better than mine. But you could do also do this query :

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT name AS FullName,  
             (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coaches WHERE coaches.name=FullName) AS NrOfSports  
       FROM coaches  
   ) tmp  
     WHERE NrOfSports>1
```